# Cookie is not included in request header / Server side cannot read req.cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, express-session

I am learning and applying authentication for my blog website!

I am using `express-session` to handle logins. Cookie on the browser & server sessions works fine.

[image: Cookies]

However, **I am having trouble retrieving cookies on the server-side express app**. I tried the following:

- With cookie-parser, req.cookies & req.signedCookies both returns `[Object: null prototype]`.
- Setting CORS
- req.cookie & req.header.cookie returns `undefined`
- I can see a "Cookie" header from my connection in the browser network tab.

My code / settings are as follows:

```js
function auth (req, res, next) {
  // Problem: Cannot read browser cookie of HTTP requests.
  console.log('Based on browser', req.cookie, req.cookies, req.signedCookies);
  next();
}

router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => { // ... }
```

*Middlewares*

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  credentials: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser())  // Also tried with secret option.
app.use(session({
  secret: 'top-secret',
  resave: true,
  rolling: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: store, // this is working
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'Development',
    sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'Development' ? 'lax' : 'none'
  }
}))
```

Thank you in advance :)

**Edit 1**: My fetch code:
[image: fetch code]

Comment: Are you making ajax requests? Because those don't transmit cookies by default. (edit: *cross-origin ones*)

Comment: Hello Chris, I made request with the fetch API

Comment: Yes, but from a different server I assume? That means you need to enable the transmission of cookies by adding `credentials: include` to the fetch options. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#syntax

Comment: I didn't include that option before. But adding that option unfortunately did not solve the issue. :(

Comment: Can you show relevant fetch code?

Comment: I edited my post which includes the fetch code.

Comment: You have to do this for all fetch requests, because the cookie needs to be set for the correct server, i.e. localhost:4000. A cookie set by localhost:3000 will never be included in a request to localhost:4000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using http only you should consider 2 things:

**Step1 while request in client side:**
you should send request like this:

```
        const req = await fetch("http://localhost:7000/api/auth/login", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: formData.get("email"),
        password: formData.get("password"),
      }),
    });
    const data = await req.json();
```

**step 2 in express:**

```
const allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:8000"];
    const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
   if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
  callback(null, true);
    } else {
     var msg =
    "The CORS policy for this site does not " +
    "allow access from the specified Origin.";
     callback(new Error(msg), false);
   }
 },
optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
 credentials: true,
 };
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

now you can get coockies in express by using **req.cookies.nameOfCookiesWhichYouSendThroughCoockieParser**

Comment: Thank you. I realized that cookie does pass normally under all HTTP requests except GET. Idk why but I can get around that.

Comment: When you get the cookie in the first request. you can access cookies to all request methods: GET, POST,PUT... you should set your client headers to share cookies alongside other requests and maybe you have set a short expire time for your cookie.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using axios (React) + Express-js on Node-js

**On the client side- In order to get the cookie from the server:** 
Simply set `withCredentials: true` in the axios request, you can use this config example:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  withCredentials: true,
};
```

**On the server side- In order to get the cookie from the client:** 
You also need to set `withCredentials: true` in the axios request, 
And you need to install [`cookie-parser`](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html) library on the server:

```
npm i cookie-parser
```

Import this library:

```
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
```

And use the cookieParser middleware:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

And finally, `req.cookies` should return the list of your cookies.